# Is there a Future<T> type in .NET?

Tags: .net

My Google-fu is failing me -- Is there a Future<T> type in .NET?

I thought I remembered seeing some code for that, but maybe I was reading Java....

By the way, my musing started after reading [This Article](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/effective-concurrency-prefer-futures-to-baked-in-async-apis/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Future<T>` is a part of the [Task Parallel Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/04/06/9534426.aspx) and was renamed to `Task<TResult>` in beta 1.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/a3d36832-c81e-4e51-b594-fdbc9d7c0e31/

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly remembering the [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/01/30/futuret_2D00_queries_2D00_with_2D00_hql_2D00_and_2D00_criteria.aspx) one?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. There is such a Java class, which "[represents the result of an asynchronous computation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)".

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet has one in his [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx). He also mentions it in is [First encounters with Reactive Extensions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/16/first-encounters-with-reactive-extensions.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is [future keyword](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Futures) in [Delphi Prism](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/) as well.